# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" while making chart in ASP.NET MVC view (Razor code)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I tried adding a pie chart in my view using ASP.NET MVC and I am getting an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at line 4 in the code where I create a new instance of the chart.

Here is my code in the view:

```
@model ProjectViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DashBoard";
    Chart myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Projects")
        .AddSeries("Default", chartType: "Pie",
            xValue: Model.Names, xField: "Name",
            yValues: Model.Values, yFields: "Sales")
        .Write();
}
```

Can somebody please tell me the solution?

Comment: Is `Models` or one of the members you reference for it null?

Comment: No, the values are not null, but if I pull breakpoints, It says that chart is null.

Answer (score 1):

This error you will get once the x or y values is null
make sure you have values in x and y